# Wp-query and column blocks

Tags: wp-query, thumbnails, columns

Maybe this is asking too much, but the new blocks give a simple way to add columns that work well responsively. ie you can just drop image thumbs into column blocks and they work perfectly on mobile and desktop alike.

Is there a way I can get WP-query to output `the_post_thumbnail` as described by my arguments (12 published posts of category x) inside 3 column rows?

Answer (score 0):

The new block editor gives lots of possibilities to arrange information **inside one post**. What you are asking for is the **arrangement of multiple posts**. That's not a task for the block editor but for the theme.

So, for your question: it depends on the theme whether this is possible. If you are designing your own theme, it is a matter of applying the right css to the post containers. This is a matter of your html/css skills, so it is not WordPress specific and hence outside the scope of this site. You may want to take a look at [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), though.

Comment: hi @cjbj im not designing a theme per se, just a bit stuck with a website im making using twenty nineteen. I have the css skills but before i can style it up i need to get each post that is spat out by the loop to be inside a 3 column row, which is where im stuck. This is my code that needs each post to fall inside a three column row.
            <div>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
            </div>

Comment: thanks for the flex box tip